# If statement to filter file extensions

Tags: php

I am creating a script which allows the user to upload images but now I want to include a simple if statement which will accept only gif and png . Here is my code but it doesn’t  seem  to be working the way it has to .

```
#extention filter
$allowed = array("image/gif","image/png");  
if(!in_array($files,$allowed)){
 $error_message = 'Only jpg, gif, and pdf files are allowed.';
  $error = 'yes';
  echo $error_message;
  exit();
}   #extention
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    $filename=$_FILE['name']['filename_in_html'];  //you can change this with your filename
    $allowed='png,jpg';  //which file types are allowed seperated by comma

    $extension_allowed=  explode(',', $allowed);
    $file_extension=  pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(array_search($file_extension, $extension_allowed))
    {
        echo "$extension_allowed allowed for uploading file";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$extension_allowed is not allowed for uploading file";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$file_type = $_FILES['name']['type']; //returns the mimetype

$allowed = array("image/png", "image/gif", "application/pdf");
if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
  $error_message = 'Only png, gif files are allowed.';
  $error = 'yes';
}
```

Hope its may help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/path/emptyextension.');
var_dump($path_parts['extension']);
```

This will return the exact extension and you can compare it as needed.